# Remove keyboard notification when ViewController disappears

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uikeyboard

How can I remove keyboard notification?

I put observer on keyboard open and close.

I change the view size depend on keyboard is open or close.

Comment: self.view.endEditing(true) to simply hide keyboard

Answer (score 5):

Try this to remove keyboard open show observers,

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

you should remove observers either in `deinit` Or `viewDidDisappear` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the code at two place.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
```

And on this one

```
deinit{
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code hope it works for you

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
        }
```