# Prevent an observer from getting notified

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, observers

I have a problem using the `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` function because I have a 2 viewController application, where the second view is presented as a popover on top of the first

The problem is that I set an observer to slide the view up when the keyboard is showed and now when the user starts typing on the popover view textfield the first view that appears in the background slides up as well because is observing too

I want to know if there is a way to prevent the first view from sliding up when the keyboard shows on the popover view

This is what I am using to slide the view when keyboard shows

```
viewDidLoad() {
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }
        }
```

```
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                    self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.frame.height + 20
                }
            }
        }

        @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
            }
        }
```

I have the same code on both views

This is the situation

[image: gif of what happens]

Comment: Please attach a .gif or video or screenshot what happens actually, so that anyone can understand your problem easily.

Comment: I didn't think of that, good idea! @AnkurLahiry

Answer (score 0):

Remove the notification observer when you are being disappeared from the view.

In your first view controller add the following line

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

and in viewDidAppear , add `addObservers`

Reference : [Remove keyboard notification when ViewController disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395298/remove-keyboard-notification-when-viewcontroller-disappears)

Comment: I found this on the documentation
"Note
If a view controller is presented by a view controller inside of a popover, this method is not invoked on the presenting view controller after the presented controller is dismissed."
Any ideas? @AnkurLahiry
The fact that the view doesn't disappear completely does not help